# How to get data from a NSDictonary in a NSDictonary in a property list?

Tags: ios, struct, nsdictionary, property-list

I have a plist with an `NSDictonary` in an `NSDictonary` and I wonder if there is an easy way to get data from the sub `NSDictonary`.

Here is a picture of how my plist looks like:
[image: my plist]

I want to get the data from the `NSDictonary's` `Pistol`, `Magnum` and `ShotGun`.

I thought there would be a method in NSDictonary like this `dictonaryForKey` but there isnt one and I cant seem to find something similar.

```
NSString *plistURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Guns" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *guns = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistURL];
NSArray *array = [dict allValues];
NSDictionary *pistol = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:array[0]];
NSNumber *number = [newDict valueForKey:@"Damage"];
```

Or is there a way to set values in a `struct`?

Comment: can u show whats in the main dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over complicating things for yourself. Try the following code, it creates your initial dictionary, then directly accesses the sub dictionary by its key value.

```
NSString *plistURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Guns" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *guns = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistURL];

NSDictionary *pistol = guns[@"Pistol"];
NSNumber *number = pistol[@"Damage"];
```

Note: The last two lines utilize modern Objective C syntax.

Comment: I couldnt accept it for another 8 min before, and then I had to leave but now its accepted ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use Key Value Coding:

```
NSString *plistURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Guns" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *guns = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistURL];
NSDictionary *pistol = [guns valueForKeyPath:@"Pistol"];
```

Or if you want to get the damage directly:

```
NSNumber *damage = [guns valueForKeyPath:@"Pistol.Damage"];
```

From the documentation:

```
- (id)valueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
```

> Returns the value for the derived property identified by a given key
>   path. The default implementation gets the destination object for each
>   relationship using valueForKey: and returns the result of a
>   valueForKey: message to the final object.

Comment: Oh I didnt know the valueForKeyPath worket for Dictonaries aswell :P

Comment: It does, and it is very powerful!